# Programs running as admin, but not prompting for credentials

Tags: windows, administrator, uac, runas

UPDATE: The only resolution I could find was to remove the user account from the workstation and recreate it. I know that's not a legitimate "fix", but it is technically a legitimate workaround in my case.

I login to my company owned, domain joined workstation normally as a standard domain user (or so I believe). Sometimes, I need to run various programs as a separate, privileged domain account. Previously, when I would try to do so, I would get a UAC prompt for those credentials. I liked it this way and am trying to figure out what I changed to make it behave as it does now:
Now, when I try to run a program as an administrator, it simply opens the program as an administrator, but with my current user account. This prevents me from being able to make network changes (such as Active Directory, DHCP, DNS, etc.) which require that I use the privileged domain account credentials.

I checked Control Panel > User Accounts and noticed that my "user" account was running as an administrator, so I changed it to Standard User and logged out. When I logged back in and checked again, it said User next to my username. However, it did not change the behavior of the program and did not prompt me for admin credentials when I tried to run the program as an administrator.

I would *really* like to avoid deleting my local user account from the workstation and recreating it, if possible.

I know I can run a specific program as a specific user, but I'd rather set a program to *always* run as administrator **and** *always* prompt me for my privileged user credentials.

Comment: Set up a new, test Standard User Account. Log in and see if the new account works correctly. If so, the user profile for your regular account is most likely damaged and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Your description is confusing.  You first describe an AD domain environment.  You then talk about having a local account on the machine.  So [edit] your question to clarify if the machine actually is connected to an AD domain.  Sounds like your IT Administrator has pushed updates to your machine.  Have you talked to your IT Administrator about your issues?

Comment: There's a policy or setting applying to your computer setting your regular account as local administrator. You need to talk to your IT folks about this.

Comment: i know this isn't exactly what you're after but a good workaround for now until you solve this is to hold down shift, right click the program and select "run as different user". This will pull up that credentials window.

Comment: if it happens again, check in the Edit Local Users and Groups console (`lusrmgr.msc`) to see whether your user is a member of the Administrators group, (or any sub-group). Changing the account "Type" in control panel does not necessarily remove the admin permissions